# Compose - AnimatedVisibility and offset

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

When adding an enter and exit transition to `AnimatedVisibility`, if the composable animated has an offset modifier, the transition is not visible:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = visible,
            enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(1000)),
            exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(1000))
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello, world!", modifier = Modifier
                    // This will make the transition not working
                    //.offset(100.dp, 0.dp)
            )
        }
        Button(onClick = { visible = !visible }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }
```

This is the animation without the offset:

[image: No offset]

and this is the animation with the offset:

[image: Offset]

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put the offset modifier onto the `Text`. Put it onto `AnimatedVisibility` instead:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = visible,
            enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(1000)),
            exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(1000)),
            modifier = Modifier.offset(100.dp, 0.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello, world!")
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about it. :)